# Как перенести последние k букв слова в начало?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано слово. Перенести последние k его букв в начало

```
string = str(input('Введите слово: '))
n = int(input('Сколько букв перенести в начало: '))
i = -1
k = 0
for _ in range(n):
    a =  string.replace(string[i], string[k])
k += 1
i -= 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
text = input('Введите слово: ')
k = int(input('Сколько букв перенести в начало: '))

new_text = text[-k:] + text[:k]
print(new_text)
```

Например, для `text = 'abcdef'` и `k = 3`:

- `text[-k:]` вернет `"def"`
- `text[:k]` вернет `"abc"`

---

**PS.**

- В python3 `input` и так возвращает строку
- Циклы не нужны, а `replace` может побочные эффекты вызвать
- Используйте срезы (slice)

Comment: @ДимаБогатырев, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)